# Add HSTS to an Azure API Management Service

Tags: azure-api-management, hsts

On Azure, I created a new API Management Service and behind it I connected all the APIs.

After a penetration test, there was only one vulnerability detected from the security company that is `No HSTS Header observed`.

[image]

The HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) policy defines a time-frame where a browser must connect to the web server via HTTPS. Without a Strict Transport Security policy the web application may be connect to the application using unencrypted HTTP. The application does not specify any HSTS configuration.

**Potential Impact**

If the web application mixes usage of HTTP and HTTPS, an attacker can manipulate pages in the unsecured area of the application or change redirection targets in a manner that the switch to the secured page is not performed or done in a manner, that the attacker remains between client and server.

If there is no HTTP server, an attacker in the same network could simulate a HTTP server and motivate the user to click on a prepared URL by a social engineering attack.

So, my question is: how can I apply this policy across my APIs?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to implement a policy in azure api management we can only implement inbound and out bound policies which are pre defined.

You can define/implement HSTS in you api if you are using asp.net core .

Here we use `app.UseHsts();` to implement the HTST policies in the api .
For detailed and Indepth explanation refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was quite sure about it but I was looking for a confirmation because the penetration company raised this issue.